# React Native - Android Emulator Device

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

For several hours now, I have tried to change the emulator that Android uses with no luck, the application will launch and run fine on the default Nexus 5. by using `react-native run-android`. but trying to run it on another emulator crashes, If I try to build from Android Studio, it will not connect to Metro.

I either launch the emulator in Android studio and it won't connect to the Metro bundler.

Or I launch it from the command line with CLI `react-native run-android` and it launches Nexus 5 and I can't do shit.

Why can't the emulators easier like ios (facepalm).

Please help me easily launch my react native app on a different emulator than the default. It's outrageous this is not a choice or option. I have tried for hours.

F**ken ANDROID HELL
[image]

Comment: It literally came down fo the order in which the emulators were being launched. And still is the case, just have to be mindful of it.